# Spark Internal class Kryo registration

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, kryo

I'm new to Spark I'm using 2.4.4 with kryo. The spark job will write around 100 part files and then fails by throwing the following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: 
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.WriteTaskResult
Note: To register this class use: 
kryo.register(org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.WriteTaskResult.class);
```

As suggested in the exception I can register

```
kryo.register(org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.WriteTaskResult.class);
```

But the problem is, it is an internal Spark class, the question I have is, is it ok to register this internal class? shouldn't it be taken care of by Kryo or Spark itself as long as it is an internal class? What is the right way to fix this problem?

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I registered the following classes and it worked

```
kryo.register(classOf[org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.WriteTaskResult])
kryo.register(classOf[org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ExecutedWriteSummary])
kryo.register(classOf[org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BasicWriteTaskStats])
kryo.register(classOf[org.apache.spark.internal.io.FileCommitProtocol])
kryo.register(classOf[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow])
```

Thanks
Raj